# How do I uninstall Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS from my Dell Inspirion 15 7548?

Tags: 14.04

[These are my partitions, but I can't tell which is which. I don't want to delete the wrong one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa0Sa.jpg)So as you can already tell, I am pretty much a newbie to the world of Linux. The only reason why I installed it (via flash drive) was because I just wanted to test out the different types of available distributions. My laptop has no C-D drive so I can't use a recovery disk. Are there any other alternatives? Also, I would appreciate it if y'all could give me advise on some good Linux distributions. Thank you in advance.

My laptop is dual booted with Windows 10 (Pre-Installed) and of course, Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (Installed via flash drive).

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201408-15450/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 0):

The flash drive you used to install Ubuntu should have a live environment you can boot to.  This is the same environment you booted to in order to install Ubuntu in the first place.

There should be a utility (e. g. `gparted`) that you can use to remove the Ubuntu installation from the laptop.  Be sure not to remove the Windows partition if you still want to use that operating system.